# problema con el IN en devolución de datos

Tags: php, sql, base-de-datos

Estoy teniendo problemas en la impresión de datos, primero obtener un array que transformamos en string para meterlo en consulta preparada

```
        $tiendasArray = json_decode('[' . $parametros['tiendas'] . ']', true);

if ($parametros['fecha_inicio'] != '')
        {
            $filtro .= " AND f.fecha >= :fecha_inicio ";
            $array_sql[':fecha_inicio'] = formatear_fecha('a', $parametros['fecha_inicio']);
        }
        if ($parametros['fecha_fin'] != '')
        {
            $filtro .= " AND f.fecha <= :fecha_fin ";
            $array_sql[':fecha_fin'] = formatear_fecha('a', $parametros['fecha_fin']);
        }
        if ($parametros['centro_id'] != '')
        {
            $filtro .= " AND f.centro_id = :centro_id ";
            $array_sql[':centro_id'] = $parametros['centro_id'];
        }
        else
        {
            $tiendasArray = json_decode('[' . $parametros['tiendas'] . ']', true);

            $centro_id = 0;
            foreach($tiendasArray as $tiendas){
                $centro_id.="$tiendas"."','";
            }
            $centro_id=substr($centro_id,0,-3);
            $filtro .= " AND f.centro_id IN(:centro_id)";
            $array_sql[':centro_id'] = $centro_id;


        }

$centro_id = 0;
            foreach($tiendasArray as $tiendas){
                $centro_id.="$tiendas"."','";
            }
            $centro_id=substr($centro_id,0,-3);
            $filtro .= " AND f.centro_id IN(:centro_id)";
            $array_sql[':centro_id'] = $centro_id;

        $sql_resultados=$link->prepare("SELECT f.* FROM vent_factura AS f WHERE f.activo = 1 " . $filtro);
```

y luego la ejecutamos

```
$sql_resultados->execute($array_sql);
```

ahora voy a tratar de explicarme bien, el problema radica en la renderización de datos que tengo un problema que no entiendo.

Para empezar la query probada como sale en HeidiSQL u otro programa me saca todos los datos. Pero el problema está que en la página solo muestra de un grupo de datos , por ejemplo en la consulta van tres valores, pues solo coge el primero mientras que en el programa sql funciona bien. no entiendo el problema

Comment: *...el problema radica en la renderización de datos*  ¿renderización de **cuáles** datos?... *Pero el problema está que en la página solo muestra de un grupo de datos* ... ¿en **qué** página?  ¿cuál es el código que usas para mostrar los datos?

Comment: Muestra el sql entero, no sirve de mucho solo saber que en la sentencia hay un AND f.centro_id IN tal, no obstante puede haber una solucion.

Comment: con la consulta consigo una serie de datos por ejemplo de tres id, y me saca un listado, pues en mi tabla solo se muestran los datos del primer id mientras que en el heidisql se ven todos

Comment: Pero es que no podemos ayudarte si no muestras la parte del código problemática... hablas de datos, de una página, de una tabla... pero **¿dónde está todo eso de lo que hablas? ¿cómo lo construyes?** Por favor [edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/168805/edit) y pon la parte del código que falla, de lo contrario va a ser imposible poderte ayudar. Se supone que después del `execute` tú haces un manejo de los datos para presentarlos, ¿no?. Si no presenta bien la información significa que estás cometiendo errores en ese manejo, pero ese código falta en la pregunta.

Comment: No obstante hay cosas que no van a salir de ninguna forma en ese php, construyes mal ese $filtro

Comment: a ver el programa funciona perfectamente si no agrego parte del filtro de arriba, el problema está en ese trozo. antes la tabla no era específica e imprimía todos los datos pero ahora necesito solo los que traigo en el array inicial, así que pensaba que el problema está ahí

Comment: @mantamusica mira la respuesta que acabo de poner a ver si te vale

Comment: En Stackoverflow hay varios usuarios expertos en distintas áreas de la programación. Si tú expones tu problema de una forma clara, se te puede ayudar no solamente a resolver el problema actual, sino también a optimizar tu código. Por eso, siempre conviene una breve exposición del problema explicando el contexto. Estoy casi seguro de que tu programa se puede optimizar y de que esos filtros de los que hablas se pueden hacer de una mejor manera. Pero sin entender la situación es difícil poder sugerir una solución que sea óptima.

Comment: Y no puede ser que el problema lo tengas aqui? : `if ($parametros['centro_id'] != '')
        {
            $filtro .= " AND f.centro_id = :centro_id ";
            $array_sql[':centro_id'] = $parametros['centro_id'];
        }`

Comment: no puede ser que $parametros['centro_id'] sean un array? y que al preparar la sentencia solo te coja la primera posición del array? ¿Cómo se rellenan los datos dentro de $parametros[]?

Answer (score 0):

Primero, `$centro_id` no lo inicialices a `0`, inicializalo como una cadena vacía mejor `""` ya que después vas a concatenar.

Después, no estás concatenando las cosas bien preparadas para el sql:

```
$centro_id.="$tiendas"."','";
```

con un array que tenga : `["a","b","c","d"]` por ejemplo, generaría una cadena tal que así `"a','b','c','d','"`, cuando lo que tú buscas es que quede así `"'a','b','c','d'"`, para lo cual deberías crear el string de la siguiente forma:

```
    $centro_id = "";
    foreach($tiendasArray as $tiendas){
        $centro_id.="'".$tiendas."',";
    }
    $centro_id=substr($centro_id,0,-2);
    // importante ahora tienes que quitar un caracter menos
```

Comment: me da de solución $centro_id  = 352:string ''1','21','4'

Comment: aunque ponga bien el filtro no se que pasa que me sigue imprimiendo solo los del id 1 y no coge los del 21 y el 4